# SQL update if exist, insert if not exist not working

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, exists

I want to update a record if it exists or create a new record if it does not exist yet but somehow it is throwing an error and I cannot find out why..

I want to update the status of a customer if it exists or create a new customer if not exist.

my query:

```
$sql = "SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM sms WHERE number = '123456789' AND customer_id = '1' ) THEN UPDATE sms SET stat = '1' ELSE INSERT INTO sms (number, customer_id, stat) values ('+32485386902', '1', '1') END"
```

This throws error:

> [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near `UPDATE sms SET stat = '1' ELSE INSERT INTO sms (number, customer_id, stat) value` at line 1

However if I change the update and insert into to 1 and 2 it shows 1 if exist, or 2 if not.

Can anyone help me out :) ? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe i'm wrong, but i think SELECT does return columns and not perform any INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE query. However, with MySQL you can use the REPLACE keyword that will solve your problem. But keep in mind that the solution will be only available in a mySQL environment (if you change of RDBMS, will not work).

Comment: Make the number a primary key then use `insert into ... on duplicate update`.

Comment: Besides the `$sql` var.. where is the `PHP` and the `if-statement`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding a second key to the customer_id made this working:

$sqlsms = "INSERT INTO sms (number, customer_id, stat) VALUES('$phone', '$compID', '$smsPromo') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE stat = '$smsPromo'";

Answer (score 0):

In SELECT query you always must have clause FROM. I recommend you first write a SELECT query to know if the record exists, then if the record not exists you can run INSERT else UPDATE. You can't use `SELECT * FROM sms` in subquerys, it's mistake sixtaxe.